# matlab meta.class handle to deleted class after cd()

Tags: matlab, oop, metaclass

**My Problem**

If I have a local class called SomeClass. And I run the following script.m:

SomeClass.m

```
classdef SomeClass
end
```

script.m

```
t = ?SomeClass;
t
cd('SomeDir');
t
cd('..');
t
```

Then Matlab (R2018b) will output the following:

```
t = 

  class with properties:

                     Name: 'SomeClass'
              Description: ''
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 0
              Enumeration: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 0
          InferiorClasses: {0×1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: [0×0 meta.package]
     RestrictsSubclassing: 0
             PropertyList: [0×1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [2×1 meta.method]
                EventList: [0×1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0×1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [0×1 meta.class]


t = 

  handle to deleted class


t = 

  handle to deleted class
```

So after the cd command the variable t now points to:

```
handle to deleted class
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. What can I do to solve/circumvent it?

**Bonus information**

In the actual software I am writing (50K lines monster), the above problems happens in almost all variables containing meta.class'es. Yes I said almost :) This is the stranges part, so sometimes it happens for some classes and not others? So in the particular case, where I ran into this problem, I have two classes in subpackages, something like:

```
package.subpackage.ExampleReport
package.subpackage.FlowchartReport
```

The two classes are almost identical and subclasses of the same baseclass. All variables of ?package.subpackage.ExampleReports still persists even after the cd command. But not the ones pointing to ?package.subpackage.FlowchartReports. Sadly I have not been able to reproduce this in a simple example.

**Why I can't just skip the cd() command**

I run a windows command line program using the system() command. In this particular case it is important that I am located on the correct path for the call to function properly.

Comment: I do not experience any of the behaviors here exposed for some of my classes....

Comment: Which is your folder structure? Do you have `private` folders? Do you have `+` folders? Are there `static` elements? Which is the general structure of those classes?

Comment: @Brethlosze are you also using R2018b? The 'SomeClass' is literally just empty, I have added it to the question. The packages are located inside folders with the same names prefixed with '+'. The classes inside these packages are simple POMO classes

Comment: I think after change of directory the class definition is perceived to be changed by MATLAB. This causes the metaclass to be deleted. See "Metaclass Object Lifecycle" section in https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/using-class-metadata.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, and found this question (my own). Since it doesn't have any answers, I will share how I solved the problem.

I created a class (MetaContainer) which stores the name of the metaclass, and then if the metaclass is deleted, the MetaContainer recreates it using meta.class.fromName()

```
classdef MetaContainer < handle
    % MetaContainer is created to retain the value of a Matlab metaclass
    % even if Matlab deletes it at some point.
    
    properties
        Meta
        Name
    end
    
    methods
        function self = MetaContainer(meta)
            % Constructor
            %
            % Parameters
            % ----------
            % meta : metaclass
            %     The metaclass that is to be protected from deletion

            assert(isa(meta, 'meta.class'), 'Invalid metaclass for MetaContainer');
            self.Meta = meta;
            self.Name = meta.Name;
        end
        
        function result = Get(self)
            % Returns
            % -------
            % metaclass
            %     The contained metaclass, if Matlab has deleted it then it
            %     is restored.

            if ~isvalid(self.Meta)
                self.Meta = meta.class.fromName(self.Name);
            end

            result = self.Meta;
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: You should really not have class definitions in the current directory. Add your package directory the the MATLAB path, then you can CD around all you want without any definition going out of scope.

Comment: The example with SomeClass is simply to reproduce the problem. In the actual code the classes are on the MATLAB path, and It still happens sometimes. I haven't yet figured out why this happens. If you understand why the error occurs, then please elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Well, in the question it says "If I have a local class called SomeClass", I presumed that was a key part of the problem. This should not be happening with a class on the search path. If it does, you could consider talking to your MathWorks representative, or submit a bug report.